# IndexError: index out of bounds in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am a beginner in pandas. I want to extract a column from excel file to python array with pandas.I want to run a loop through whole column. I want to print 1st data in that column.Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile("Summary.xlsx")  # Load the excel workbook
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")  # Parse the sheet into a dataframe
df['transactionqtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transactionqtr'],errors ='coerce')
df['commencementdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['commencementdate'],errors ='coerce')
df=df.dropna()
df['transactionqtr'] = df['transactionqtr'].apply(lambdax:x.date().strftime('%m%d%y'))
df['commencementdate'] = df['commencementdate'].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m%d%y'))
arr1 = df['transactionqtr'][1][1]
arr2 = df['commencementdate'][1][1]
print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

But it shows IndexError: index out of bounds in this line:

```
arr1 = df['transactionqtr'][1][1]
arr2 = df['commencementdate'][1][1]
```

How should I solve this? Please also guide me for better code.

Comment: Could you include the entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) or [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
#if need list
arr1 = df['transactionqtr'].dt.strftime('%m%d%y').tolist()
arr2 = df['commencementdate'].dt.strftime('%m%d%y').tolist()

#if need numpy array
arr1 = df['transactionqtr'].dt.strftime('%m%d%y').values
arr2 = df['commencementdate'].dt.strftime('%m%d%y').values
```

And for first value use indexing with `[]`:

```
a = arr1[0]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tolist'
It shows this error.

Comment: What is `print (df.head())`  after `df=df.dropna()` ?

Comment: I didn't use this.

Comment: Check 6th row. There is it.

Comment: Yes I have used df=df.dropna() but didn't use this print (df.head())

Comment: Yes, so please add it and what it return?